# If hydrogen bonding in water was weaker, what happens to H+ ion concentration?

Tags: acid-base, water, hydrogen-bond

> Water ionization becomes much less evident if the hydrogen bonds are just a few percent stronger but pure water contains considerably more $\ce{H+}$ ions if they are few percent weaker.

I found this line in some article. You can even copy/paste this line on search bar of Google. I didn't understood the latter part of this statement which is "but pure water contains considerably more $\ce{H+}$ ions if they are few percent weaker". The author is indicating to which of the following three situations?

1. only $\ce{H+}$ ion concentration will increase
2. both $\ce{H+}$ and $\ce{OH-}$ will increase
3. $\ce{H+}$ will increase and $\ce{OH-}$ will decrease that is the equilibrium constant remains same.

Comment: Sorry could you rephrase the section in the middle as it is very unclear and confusing. Also what do you mean by 'H='

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The article by Martin Chaplin 'Water's Hydrogen Bond Strength' (arXiv:[0706.1355](https://arxiv.org/abs/0706.1355) **[cond-mat.soft]**, no evidence of peer review) is discussing how changes to the properties of water would alter life.

If the hydrogen bonding in water was stronger, there would be less ionization (less $\ce{H+}$ and less $\ce{OH-}$).

If the hydrogen bonding in water was weaker, there would be more ionization (more $\ce{H+}$ and more $\ce{OH-}$).